# React Native + Realm JS: How to sort by multiple properites.

Tags: realm

This works to sort by Last Name, but I would like a secondary sort by First Name (bb_first_name). The docs sugjest it is possible, but I can find the right syntax to make it work.

```
const array = this.realm.objects("Student").sorted('bb_last_name', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = this.realm
      .objects("Faculty")
      .sorted(["bb_first_name", "bb_last_name"]);
    return array;
```